# VML issues after applying KB2482017

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, vml

Up until now I had a well functioning interactive graph on a page rendered using [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).  After some patches were pushed, it stopped rendering in IE7.  After some trial and error I found that neither flot, nor any other js drawing library (that used excanvas or some derivative for IE fallback) would render on IE7 or IE8 on Windows XP with KB2482017.  Windows 7, IE8 with the patch is not affected.  I have not tested Vista.

After some digging it seems even basic VML is broken on XP with the patch. [Microsoft's own VML sample](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/vml/redoval.htm) fails to render.

Has anyone else seen this behavior, and if so, know a workaround?

Here is a screenshot of my reputation graph from a machine with XP, IE7, and the patch applied.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have McAfee antivirus, with HIPS 7.0 ? If so that could be the cause.
Check https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB70810 for a similar issue.

Comment: Yes, I do.  I have been applying patches to a non McAfee box to confirm.